# move discount block below order total in checkout_index_index in sidebar

Tags: layout, onepage-checkout, magento2.4

i want to move discount block below order total on one-page-checkout, like below in screenshot

[image]

I tried below code in **checkout_index_index.xml** but it is placing copon block in bottom

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are putting the component in message area (displayArea's value)</s>

Edit:
You didn't give the area for it to display so it is placed in the bottom, which is the correct behavior.

The correct area is `itemsBefore`, here is the demo display [image: demo pic] (tested in 2.4.1)